# Firebase: No Firebase App default has been created And Firebase app default already exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This firebase error keeps popping up and if I initialize it like this:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var db = firebase.firestore();
```

it gives me another error: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).

This my code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
  };
  
  const app = !firebase.app.length ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : firebase.app();

  const db = app.firestore();
  const storage = firebase.storage();

  export {db, storage};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to assign the Firebase App Instance to a variable. Also it's confusing that you are using `app` to initialize Firestore but `firebase` for storage. The follow code works perfectly for me (Vue app):

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};
  
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}

const db = firebase.firestore();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export {db, storage};
```

Comment: thank you, i tried it but it returns this error: "projectId" not provided in firebase.initializeApp.  although it is provided in firebaseConfig

Comment: @EgonAdelsberger that's wierd. Could you please share your updated code? Just blur out the credentials. I want to see  if all properties are there in the config. A screenshot of error will help too

Comment: @EgonAdelsberger I can't see the fields in config JSON. Can you confirm you have these:   apiKey, authDomain, databaseURL, projectId, storageBucket, messagingSenderId, appId, measurementId? Also these are case sensitive iirc. Can you confirm this ?

Comment: i am missing databaseURL and measurementID the rest is there - i copied the config directly from firebase

Comment: @EgonAdelsberger can you send screenshot of error from the terminal/CMD? and try to get the line number of error.

Comment: Dharmaraj - i decided to run my server again so i can take you a clean screenshot and it seems that was all i had to do since error is no longer there, thank you very much for your help and time

Comment: i mean it works perfectly fine now; thank you very much ♥

Comment: @EgonAdelsberger great! Glad to hear that.